# How to properly map IIS / to a specific Web application

Tags: iis-7

I have a server: myserver.mycompany.com
My Web server is IIS 7 on Win 2008 R2
On this server I run my app:  MyApp
Currently, for the users to access my app they need to enter: http://myserver.mycompany.com/myapp
I would like to change that, and have my app accessible by entering just my server.mycompany.com

What settings do I need to adjust to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the binding for the virtual website. You should have the MyApp listed in the tree down the left hand side of the IIS console. Select it and then use the Bindings link of the far right side of the console.

Add your domain name and link it to the IP address of the server.

If you MyApp is already a folder underneath a virtual website of myserver.mycompany.com then you would be better off moving it out to its own virtual website

You can see more about host headers and binding them here - [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)